# WebClient POST no key parameter to Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, webclient, asp.net-web-api2, http-status-code-415

I know that if you want to POST a variable to Web API with WebClient you do not include the parameter key

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string URI = "http://blablabla/api/testaction";
    string myParameters = "=TEST";

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
    }
}
```

My question is why can't you include the parameter key?

```
string myParameters = "myParam=TEST"; // doesn't work
```

What do you do if you want to pass more than one parameter?

Comment: string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters); // might it be download instead of uploaed ? If it's a post action check if you can hit the Api method in debug

Answer (score 0):

you should write parameters like

```
http://blablabla/api/testaction?parmeterName=parameterValue?pName=pValue
```

So basically I would write it like this

```
string URI = "http://blablabla/api/testaction";
string myParameters = "?param=TEST";
```

Comment: this does not work with Web Api. The route action matches but the parameter is null

Comment: Are you talking about the parameter inside the API controller ? If so, then ignor what  i have answered until now, the parameter inside the controller must be a string, and the address it self should just be the URI from my answer